# What Ties a Drupal Hook to a Particular Module?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

What Ties a Drupal Hook to a Particular Module?

In Drupal 7, every core module has an "api" file

```
$ ls modules/*/*.api.php
modules/aggregator/aggregator.api.php   modules/openid/openid.api.php
modules/block/block.api.php             modules/overlay/overlay.api.php
modules/comment/comment.api.php         modules/path/path.api.php
modules/contextual/contextual.api.php   modules/rdf/rdf.api.php
modules/dashboard/dashboard.api.php     modules/search/search.api.php
modules/field/field.api.php             modules/shortcut/shortcut.api.php
modules/field_ui/field_ui.api.php       modules/simpletest/simpletest.api.php
modules/file/file.api.php               modules/system/system.api.php
modules/filter/filter.api.php           modules/system/theme.api.php
modules/help/help.api.php               modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.api.php
modules/image/image.api.php             modules/trigger/trigger.api.php
modules/locale/locale.api.php           modules/update/update.api.php
modules/menu/menu.api.php               modules/user/user.api.php
modules/node/node.api.php
```

Each of these files contains a function that's never (?) called, but documents the existence of a hook that other modules (including 3rd party) can implement.

```
File: modules/path/path.api.php
function hook_path_delete($path) {
  db_delete('mytable')
    ->condition('pid', $path['pid'])
    ->execute();
}
```

My question: What ties a particular hook to a particular module?  Why is the `path_delete` hook included in the `path.api.php` file?  Why is the `entity_view` hook included in the `system.api.php` file?  Is this just arbitrary, after the fact  organization, or is there something in the Drupal system that ties a particular hook to a particular module?  Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooks are invoked using [`module_invoke()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke) and [`module_invoke_all()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke_all): if you look at the code for those two functions, you might be able to piece together how it works, but basically, if I add this to my module's code:

```
// Other code

$foo = module_invoke_all('foo_bar', $var1, $var2);

// More code
```

Drupal will invoke every implementation of `hook_foo_bar($var1, $var2)` it finds in enabled modules. Based on this, you should see that only thing that ties a particular hook to a particular module is a naming convention: if I call my module `foo`, my hook functions should begin with `hook_foo_`.

You are correct about nothing in `*.api.php` being called: since a module invocation is just a function call, module authors include `foo.api.php` merely for documentation purposes to inform implementors how to implement the hook.

For example, in the case above, `foo.api.php` would include a sample function like:

```
/**
 * Doxygen comments documenting the function goes here
 */
function hook_foo_bar($var1, $var2) {
  return $var1 + $var2;
}
```

But as a module implementor, I could implement `hook_foo_bar()` in a different fashion:

```
function mymodule_foo_bar($var1, $var2) {
  return $var1 - $var2;
}
```

And when `module_invoke_all()` gets called, Drupal will craft a function using the implementing module's short name (`mymodule`) and the hook name passed to `module_invoke_all()` (`foo_bar`), thus calling the function `mymodule_foo_bar()` I just defined.

The `system` module in core is a bit of a catch-all: one task for Drupal 8 is to [kill it off](http://drupal.org/node/679112) and delegate its functionality to other modules.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.  I understand the basic hook concept, but wanted confirmation there wasn't a formal tie between module and hook, that tit was just convention.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try learn hooking for drupal? it's easy:  
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/7 
 
About hook_path_delete: 
Look path.module, you'll see somewhere path_delete(...) calls. 
For example, in path_node_update() - this function called then you change current path - it's delete old path before, than create new path for node. 
Now looks where defined path_delete() function - it's placed in in path.inc file: 
In this function you'll see: module_invoke_all('path_delete', $path); - what this function do? 
It's list all modules (in drupal 7 it's cached) where defined hook_path_delete (as i show before, for yiu custom module it defined as YOURMODULENAME_path_delete, and it'll also included here), and run all these functions one by one (order of running defined by weight and filename of modules). 
So now what can you do in custom module? You can respond on this delete reaction and do some other actions - for example, delete other path that can be used for duplicating path of that node (it's just example).

p.s.
Good point for starting custom modules: http://drupal.org/contributors-guide

Comment: hook_entity_view called in comment, node, taxonomy and user modules (and may be more on contrib.modules). It's "low-level" hook, there you can track what happen with you "$entities".

Comment: I know how to use hooks, and I'm not interested in the specific of a particular hook; I'm trying to understand the module system in its entirety and in isolation so I can understand the rest of Drupal.  Your comments are useful, but don't answer my core question: What ties a hook to a particular module? Convention, or something formal.

Comment: hmm, it's visible from answer: modulename_hookname - this tier modulename with hookname.

Comment: module_hook_name is how you implement a module.  However, durpal documents its hooks inside module api files, which implies each module is "providing" a hook for other modules to implement. I was asking if that relationship was formal, or just implicit via documentation and usage.